# Push and splice not updating or deleting in vue.js

Tags: loops, vue.js, push, slice, v-for

I am trying to make a form repeater using an array and Vue v-for loop. but I could not able to push or slice anything in my array. I got some warning.
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined**

> Here is my code

```
<template>
  <b-form @submit.prevent="repeateAgain">
     <b-row
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :id="item.id"
      :key="item.id"
     >
       <b-col>
         <b-form-group>
           <b-form-input
            placeholder="Email"
           />
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-group>
          <b-form-input placeholder="Email" />
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-group>
           <b-form-input placeholder="Email" />
        </b-form-group>
      </b-col>
      <b-col>
        <b-form-group>
          <b-button
           variant="outline-danger"
            @click="removeItem(index)"
           >
            <i class="feather icon-x" />
             <span class="ml-25">Delete</span>
           </b-button>
         </b-form-group>
       </b-col>
     </b-row>
        <hr>
     <b-form-group>
       <b-button
         variant="primary"
         @click="repeateAgain"
        >
         <i class="feather icon-plus" />
         <span class="ml-25">Add</span>
       </b-button>
     </b-form-group>
  </b-form>
</template>

<script>
import {
  BForm, BFormGroup, BFormInput, BRow, BCol, BButton,
} from 'bootstrap-vue'

export default {
  components: {
    BForm,
    BRow,
    BCol,
    BButton,
    BFormGroup,
    BFormInput,
  },
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'Do the dishes',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'What to do ?',
    }],
    newTodoText: '',
    nextTodoId: 2,
  }),
  methods: {
    repeateAgain: () => {
      this.items.push({
        id: this.nextTodoId += +this.nextTodoId,
        title: this.newTodoText,
      })
      this.newTodoText = ''
    },
    removeItem: index => {
      this.items.splice(1)
      console.log(index)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I also try to delete a particular row using the slice method but it not work.
What am I forgetting??

Comment: Try changing all your functions from `removeItem: index => ()` to `removeItem() {` including `data() { return { ...`

Comment: @digout thanks its working now. but when I try to click delete of first its remove all ??  ```` removeItem(index) {this.items.splice(index)  },````

Comment: this.items.splice(index, 1) - the second parameter tells how many elements you want to remove (from the index). Omitting that parameter means you want to remove the rest from the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn’t use arrow functions for `data` or `methods` in Vue, because arrow functions have their own context (`this`)

```js
repeateAgain: () => {
      this.items.push({
```

In an occasion when `repeateAgain` method is called, `this` context is undefined - that’s why the error occurs ** TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined (this)**

You should modify it like this:

```js
repeateAgain() {
      this.items.push({
```

---

#### Update

`@submit.prevent="repeateAgain"` - this is what I meant by “occasion”. Since the method is not bound to the `methods: {` object, but bound to relative context (none here - undefined) on the other hand, if it’s within a class, the class instance would be the context.

E.g: (only for demonstration, do not use this pattern)

In the following example,`this` context is an instance of MyWrappedCmp

```js
import {
  BForm, BFormGroup, BFormInput, BRow, BCol, BButton,
} from 'bootstrap-vue'

class MyWrappedCmp {
  getComponent(){
    return {
      methods: {
        repeateAgain: () => {
          // “this” context is an instance of MyWrappedCmp
          // ...
         }
      }
    }
}

const myWrapped = new MyWrappedCmp()

export default myWrapped.getComponent()
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by saying in an occasion ? Could you please give some examples when or how or why?

Comment: Updated the answer explaining it.